# how to slice a DataFrame in pandas with rows and columns slicing involved

Tags: python, pandas

I'm kind of a rookie in python so sorry in advance if I'll raise trivial questions.

I need to create a DataFrame from existing one. my new df will take input from the user and should return a specific new data frame. In my raw data, I have 5 columns of stock info :
'open', 'close', 'high', 'low' and 'volume', and a 'timestamp' column which I
already converted to datetime properly.

my user is given the option to pick one or more of the 5 data columns (i.e 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low' and 'volume'), A ticker name and a range of preferable dates. ( I succeeded with the ticker name and the time)
 [this is my output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6rKL.png)
now i need to create a df that has another column - 'Data Type', that gets the request of the user, so my output shoud look, for instance, something like this:

```
 timestamp      ticker_name    data type      
2018-02-26         HP            67.35
2018-02-23         HP            701271
```

if the user asked to see only the 'open' and the 'volume' values of HP between

```
2018-02-23  to 2018-02-26 .
```

I've been struggling with this for Hours. any help will be highy appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have You seen this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

First off, be careful because "open" has its own meaning in python. Make sure you are treating it like a string by using quotes.

If you want only columns ['open','close'], you would do `return_df = df[['open','close']]`.

If you want only rows with timestamps between 2018-02-23  to 2018-02-26 you can do `return_df = df[(df.timestamp >= '2018-02-03') & (df.timestamp <= '2018-02-26')]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want a combination of things.  IMO the simplest way is to set the `Timestamp` column to be the index so you can use the timestamp slicing.  Then use `loc` to do the rest.

```
df.set_index('Timestamp')[start:end].loc[df.Ticker == 'HP', ['open', 'volume']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple slice of the dataframe:

```
s = "2018-01-17"
e = "2018-02-24"
_type = "open"
ticker = "HP"
df[(df.index >= s) & (df.index <= e) & (df.ticker_name == ticker)][["ticker_name",_type]]
```