# How to create new column from given data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a new dataframe of 2 columns. First column is `id` and second column is `predictions`. I want to create a dataframe with first column `id` which is taken from `testdata` and `predictions` is an array of `0's` and `1's`. Column names should be `id` and `predictions`.

Sample data:

[image]

My new create dataframe should be like this:

Expected output:

```
id      predictions
3242        0
3246        1
7655        1
1324        0
4643        1
```

I tried following code but I am getting some error please check screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you create sample data and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Check my edited question. I have added testdata and expected output which I need to submit as a csv file.

Comment: [PD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285613/5033247)

Comment: Thank you. What is completely `error`?

Comment: @jezrael I want to create a new dataframe with 2 columns 1) `id` 2) `predictions`. `id` column should have `id` of testdata and `predictions` see in screenshot, should be the second column. Also both columns should have name `id` and `predictions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need if lenght of `testdata` is same as `predictions`:

Test it:

```
print (len(testdata))

print (len(predictions))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':testdata['id'], 'predictions':predictions})
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: array length 31349 does not match index length 31350`

Comment: @stonerock - so need remove last value from `predictions` for same length?

Comment: @stonerock - if yes, use `df = pd.DataFrame({'id':testdata['id'], 'predictions':predictions[:-1]})`

Comment: Now I get ValueError: array length 31348 does not match index length 31350

Comment: @stonerock - so need `df = pd.DataFrame({'id':testdata['id'].values[:-1], 'predictions':predictions})`

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the arrays are equal

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':testdata['id']})
df["Predictions"] = predictions
```