# Trying to access column by index number in a pandas df. The dataframe is created by value.counts() function. It does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access a column by its index number in a Pandas data-frame using iloc:

```
 new = df_new.iloc[:,0]
```

throws out the error :

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Other posts on iloc show them working fine. Don't understand why is this happening with me . Please help !!

The data-frame is :

> ```
> Games                3862
> Entertainment         535
> Education             453
> Photo & Video         349
> Utilities             248
> Health & Fitness      180
> Productivity          178
> Social Networking     167
> Lifestyle             144
> Music                 138
> Shopping              122
> Sports                114
> Book                  112
> Finance               104
> Travel                 81
> News                   75
> Weather                72
> Reference              64
> Food & Drink           63
> Business               57
> Navigation             46
> Medical                23
> Catalogs               10
> ```

and was created by the code :

```
df_new=obj_df["prime_genre"].value_counts()
```

by count of the number of categories of another data-frame

Comment: Post the `df` as there are some possibilities for this

Comment: Posted the df. please check

Comment: Only two columns in this new dataframe. I want to extract only the first column from the above dataframe. Used iloc for column indexing and it gives me this error

Comment: Are you trying to extract the first **column** or first **row**? `iloc` is typically used to get rows by their index.

Comment: Can be used for column slicing as well based on index numbers [refer](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj_df["prime_genre"].value_counts()
```

returns a `pd.Series` ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)), which has only one dimension. The syntax `[:, 0]` means *select all rows, and column with index 0*. But because this is a series, it makes no sense to slice using *rows/columns*

Use

```
.iloc[0]
```

if you want the first element only.

---

If you want to keep using your df, assign this `pd.Series` to a column

```
obj_df['counts'] = obj_df["prime_genre"].value_counts()
```

Then you can slice using `obj_df[:, 0]`]

---

If you want the indexes, use simply

```
obj_df["prime_genre"].value_counts().index
```

or, if you want to use the `iloc` notation

```
obj_df["prime_genre"].value_counts().reset_index().iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: Tried it, returns me the value of corresponding to the second column and first row. That is 3862

Comment: I am trying to extract the first column i.e those containing "Games","Entertainment"..etc in a separate data-frame

Comment: how can I convert this series to a pd data-frame

Comment: @SHREYANSHUSNEH See the edited :) You can `reset_index`

Comment: Thank You !! Let me try that