# How can I select columns which are not consecutive in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I select columns which are not consecutive?

e.g.

```
index  a   b   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
```

How do I select 'a', 'c' and save it in to df1?

df1 = df.log[:, 'a''c'] but it doesn't work...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please post your expected output

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
df1=df[['a','c']]
```

to get the result

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe there is a typo. Your code should be

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c]]
```