# How Pandas read_html can get only selected columns from entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract the particular columns from the `html` page where my `html` data looks like below.

> 1) HTML DATA Format

```
            VM Name           User Name        Image Name                           Network  VCPUS  Memory(GB)  Disk(GB) Tenant     Region      KVM Host Power State                          URL               Created
0      dbsw-powerbi  anokhe@ezy.com           unknown   {u'VLAN181': [u'192.168.57.91']}      4          16       100    APP  DBS-AP-IN  dbs-appkvm03          On  https://compute.ezy.com  2018-08-02T10:30:07Z
1           pciedip  anokhe@ezy.com     dbsVDI-RHEL65   {u'VLAN181': [u'192.168.57.37']}      4          32       200    APP  DBS-AP-IN  dbs-appkvm01          On  https://compute.ezy.com  2018-04-18T06:39:38Z
2  dbs-spbdatasync1  anokhe@ezy.com    dbsVDI-RHEL510  {u'VLAN181': [u'192.168.57.156']}      1           8        50    APP  DBS-AP-IN     dbs-kvm13          On  https://compute.ezy.com  2018-04-05T09:51:29Z
3      dbsw-russian  anokhe@ezy.com  dbsVDI-WIN764-V1  {u'VLAN181': [u'192.168.57.216']}      1           4       100    APP  DBS-AP-IN  dbs-appkvm01          On  https://compute.ezy.com  2018-04-02T06:25:25Z
4   dbs-spbdatasync  anokhe@ezy.com    dbsVDI-RHEL510  {u'VLAN181': [u'192.168.57.233']}      1           8        50    APP  DBS-AP-IN     dbs-kvm13          On  https://compute.ezy.com  2018-04-02T05:03:03Z
```

I'm simply trying pandas `read_html` to get the DataFrame but unable to get the understanding to get the particular columns from the DataFrame.  I need to selected columns `['VM Name', 'User Name', 'Network', 'Region']` out of the 13 column.

> 2) code snippet

```
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)

# print(pd.read_excel('ssd.xlsx'))
# Data = pd.read_html('http://openstacksearch/vm_list.html', header=0, flavor='bs4', index_col=['VM Name', 'User Name', 'Network', 'Region'])
Data = pd.read_html('http://openstacksearch/vm_list.html', header=0, flavor='bs4')
print(Data[0].head())
```

Comment: Does it have to be in the read command or is it okay to do in another step?

Comment: @Andrew, Its Okay in another Step as well as long as it solves the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select a subset of columns you could use

```
Data = pd.read_html('http://openstacksearch/vm_list.html', header=0, flavor='bs4')
Data = Data[['VM Name', 'User Name', 'Network', 'Region']]
```

Comment: @ Andrew,  this gives an error  as below..

`Data = Data[['VM Name', 'User Name', 'Network', 'Region']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: are the list of column names consistent with the columns names you provided? As in, when you read_html() does it propagate those same names? I can't access the datasource to check

Comment: Are you using an older version of pandas? It works fine when I try it with the DF you provided in the question

Comment: see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Andrew, i'm using `0.21`.

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.21.0'

Answer (score 3):

I got solution while selecting the `DataFrame` from the processed `read_html` and then choosing the desired columns with multi-index based approach. Thanks to the Adrew for driving ideas around this..

So, code looks like below ... may be helpful for someone

```
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
###### Data Extraction ##################
'''
pd.read_html returns you a list with one element and that 
element is the pandas dataframe, i.e.
Data = pd.read_html('url') will produce a list
Data[0]  Will return a pandas DataFrame
'''
Data = pd.read_html('http://openstacksearch/vm_list.html', header=0, flavor='bs4')[0]
Data1 = Data[['VM Name', 'User Name', 'Network', 'Region']]
print(Data1)
```