# Scrape Wikipedia table to CSV in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a table from Wikipedia using python. I'm done with the code, but I'm having some issues extracting specific columns to CSV, and adding enclosing double apostrophes.

I want to extract for only the following column names:

```
Kode BPS, Nama, Ibu Kota, Populasi, Luas, Pulau.
```

Here's the result of the table:

[image]

And here's my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'}).tbody
rows = table.find_all('tr')
columns = [v.text.replace('\n','') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in range(1,len(rows)):
    tds = rows[i].find_all('td')

    if len(tds)==4:
        values = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text.replace('\n',''.replace('\xa0',''))]
    else:
        values = [td.text.replace('\n',''.replace('\xa0','')) for td in tds]

    df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
    #print(df)

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\'+'\\report.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the columns in the dataframe as:

```
columns = ['Kode BPS', 'Nama', 'Ibu Kota', 'Populasi', 'Luas', 'Pulau']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Then just insert the values required.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd
link = "https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia"
tables = pd.read_html(link,header=0)[2]
df.to_csv(tables, sep='\t')
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: Last line should be
tables.to_csv("wiki.csv", sep='\t')

Answer (score 1):

**To convert Wikipedia page's tables to CSV** ([pd.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)) ([df.empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html)) ([df.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html))**:**

```py
import pandas as pd

def wiki_to_csv(wikiurl = str):
    tname  = link.split("/")[-1]
    tables = pd.read_html(link, header=0)

    for i in range(len(tables)):
        if not tables[i].empty:
            fname = tname + " table " + str(i)
            tables[i].to_csv(fname, sep=',')
```

**To scrape that exact table and select specific columns** ([df.rename()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)) ([Select Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe))**:**

```py
import pandas as pd

link = "https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia"
df = pd.read_html(link, header=0)[2]

df = df.rename(columns={'Populasi[4]':'Populasi', 'Luas (km²)[5]':'Luas'})
df = df[['Kode BPS', 'Nama', 'Ibu kota', 'Populasi', 'Luas', 'Pulau']]

df.to_csv("Indonesia.csv", sep=',')
```

I'm not sure what issue you are having with double quotes.