# Split pandas column into multiple columns based on 'key=value' items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column contains several information in a 'key=value' format. There are almost a hundred different 'key=value' that can appear in that column but for simplicity sake I'll use this example with only 4 (`_browser, _status, _city, tag`)

```
id  name   properties
0   A      {_browser=Chrome, _status=TRUE, _city=Paris}
1   B      {_browser=null, _status=TRUE, _city=London, tag=XYZ}
2   C      {_status=FALSE, tag=ABC}
```

How can I convert this splitting the properties string column into multiple columns?

The expected output is:

```
id  name   _browser    _status    _city    tag
0   A      Chrome      TRUE       Paris       
1   B      null        TRUE       London   XYZ
2   C                  FALSE               ABC
```

Note: this value can also contain spaces (eg. `_city=Rio de Janeiro`)

Comment: Are properties in column `str` type or dict.

Comment: It's a string with the values separated by = sign

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-text-column-into-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: @Huzefa in my case I don't know how many values can be in the properties column and they don't follow a strict sequence, the item can appear in any part of the string

Comment: @eduardoftdo  does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245672/how-to-splitting-column-value-in-dataframe-into-multiple-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use `str.findall` with regex capture groups to extract key-value pairs from the `properties` column:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    [dict(l) for l in df.pop('properties').str.findall(r'(\w+)=([^,\}]+)')]))
```

Result:

```
 id name _browser _status   _city  tag
  0    A   Chrome    TRUE   Paris  NaN
  1    B     null    TRUE  London  XYZ
  2    C      NaN   FALSE     NaN  ABC
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, but how can I change the regex for when I have values with spaces in it? For example _city=Rio de Janeiro

Comment: @eduardoftdo in that case i guess you can try `df.pop(properties').str.findall(r'(\w+)=([^,\}]+)')`

Comment: @eduardoftdo Happy coding!

Comment: Is there a way to do this regex if I have spaces in the key itself?

Comment: @AsifIqbal Yes you can do that just replace the `regex` pattern with `r'([^=]+)=([^,\}]+)'`