# Split dataframe Column based on key value pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                               Id Column  Val1   Val2
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123   0.0    NaN
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124   1.0  750.0
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125   3.0  400.0
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126   NaN  200.0
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz   2.0    NaN
```

I want to convert the dataframe to this:

```
                               Id Column  Val1   Val2     Cust Region Info   Data
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123   0.0    NaN      abc         xyz  123.0
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124   1.0  750.0      abd         xyz  124.0
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125   3.0  400.0  acc hit         NaN  125.0
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126   NaN  200.0      abc         xyz  126.0
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0  abg nss         xaz  127.0
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz   2.0    NaN      evc         atz    NaN
```

From this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255719/5847282), I got a partial answer.

But how can I handle the spaces in the key and value?

Edit: There may be multiple key-value pairs (other than the ones shown in the example). So I need to handle cases for any 'n' number of columns.

Comment: `There may be multiple key-value pairs (other than the ones shown in the example). So I need to handle cases for any 'n' number of columns.` I could see your edited message here. Its always recommended to post all question's requirement in your base question itself, because if you later change it  users/future readers will be confused by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

We can use `str.findall` with regex capture groups to extract `key-value` pairs from the `Id Column` column

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df['Id Column'].str.findall(r'([^=,]+)=([^,]+)'))))
```

---

```
                               Id Column  Val1   Val2     Cust Region Info Data
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123   0.0    NaN      abc         xyz  123
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124   1.0  750.0      abd         xyz  124
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125   3.0  400.0  acc hit         NaN  125
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126   NaN  200.0      abc         xyz  126
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0  abg nss         xaz  127
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz   2.0    NaN      evc         atz  NaN
```

**`Regex` details**

- `([^=,]+)`: first capturing group

  - `[^=,]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[=,]` one or more times
- `=` : Matches the `=` character literally
- `([^,]+)` : Second capturing group

  - `[^,]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[,]` one or more times

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/gSl83h/1)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, could please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
df[["Cust Region","Info","Data"]] = df["IdColumn"].str.extract(r'^Cust=([^,]+)(?:,Region Info=([^,]*))?(?:,Data=(.*))?$', expand=True)
df
```

[Here is the Online demo for used regex](https://regex101.com/r/amBWhL/2)

Output will be as follows:

```
                                IdColumn  Val1   Val2 Cust Region Info Data
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123   0.0    NaN         abc  xyz  123
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124   1.0  750.0         abd  xyz  124
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125   3.0  400.0     acc hit  NaN  125
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126   NaN  200.0         abc  xyz  126
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0     abg nss  xaz  127
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz   2.0    NaN         evc  atz  NaN
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^Cust=              ##Checking if value starts from Cust= here.
([^,]+)             ##Creating 1st capturing group which has all values till , here.
(?:,Region Info=    ##Starting a non-capturing group , Region Info= here.
  ([^,]*)           ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has all values till , here.
)?                  ##Closing non-capturing group here.
(?:,Data=           ##Creating non-capturing group which has ,Data= here.
  (.*)              ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has all values till end of value here.
)?$                 ##Closing non-capturing group here at the end of line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply()` on column `Id Column` and get the value by splitting.

```py
df['Cust Region'] = df['Id Column'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split('=')[-1])
```

```
# print(df)

                               Id Column  Val1   Val2 Cust Region
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123  0.0     NaN         abc
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124  1.0   750.0         abd
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125  3.0   400.0     acc hit
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126  NaN   200.0         abc
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0     abg nss
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz  2.0     NaN         evc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with split by `,` and then by `=` for list of dictionaries, so possible pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split(',')]) for x in df['Id Column']]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
                               Id Column  Val1   Val2     Cust Region Info  \
0      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=123   0.0    NaN      abc         xyz   
1      Cust=abd,Region Info=xyz,Data=124   1.0  750.0      abd         xyz   
2                  Cust=acc hit,Data=125   3.0  400.0  acc hit         NaN   
3      Cust=abc,Region Info=xyz,Data=126   NaN  200.0      abc         xyz   
4  Cust=abg nss,Region Info=xaz,Data=127  -1.0  420.0  abg nss         xaz   
5               Cust=evc,Region Info=atz   2.0    NaN      evc         atz   

  Data  
0  123  
1  124  
2  125  
3  126  
4  127  
5  NaN
```