# 'DataFrame' object is not callable error when I try to create a new df

Tags: python, dataframe, object, spyder, callable

I try to create a new df out of df_exo, however the error I get is `'DataFrame' object` is not callable. `df_exo` is a DataFrame with `176, 1222` size. What is going wrong?

```py
df_features = df_exo(['INDU.NL.INTM.1.BS.M', 'INDU.NL.CONS.1.BS.M_4',\
 'INDU.NL.INTM.2.BS.M', 'INDU.NL.INTM.3.BS.M_12', 'INDU.NL.CONS.4.BS.M_10',\
 'INDU.NL.INTM.COF.BS.M_3', 'INDU.NL.INTM.COF.BS.M_4', 'INDU.NL.INVE.5.BS.M_11',\
 'INDU.NL.FOBE.7.BS.M_4', 'INDU.NL.TOT.1.BS.M_1', 'INDU.NL.TOT.6.BS.M_4',\
 'INDU.NL.INTM.2.BS.M', 'SERV.NL.TOT.2.BS.M', 'SERV.NL.TOT.3.BS.M',\
 'SERV.NL.TOT.1.BS.M_2', 'SERV.NL.TOT.1.BS.M_3', 'SERV.NL.TOT.3.BS.M_1',\ 
 'SERV.NL.TOT.3.BS.M_2', 'SERV.NL.TOT.COF.BS.M_7', 'CONS.NL.TOT.7.BS.M',\
 'CONS.NL.TOT.6.BS.M_12', 'CONS.NL.TOT.7.BS.M_1', 'CONS.NL.TOT.7.BS.M_2',\
 'CONS.NL.TOT.7.BS.M_12', 'BUIL.NL.TOT.3.BS.M_12'])
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
df_features = df_exo[['col1', 'col2']]
```

not

```
df_features = df_exo(['col1', 'col2'])
```

Reference:
[Selecting multiple columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No problem. BTW Please mark this as answer if this solved the problem.