# is it possible to select a view from a pandas dataframe for a subset of columns without slicing?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with fairly large datasets that are close to my available memory. I want to select a subset of columns based on column names and then save this data. I don't think I can use regular slicing, as in `:2` notation, so I need to select based on label or location. But it seems the only way to do this produces a copy, increasing memory usage considerably whenever I want to save a subset of the data. Is it possible to select a view without using slices? Or is there some creative way to use slices that can allow me to select arbitrarily located columns?

Consider the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1]], columns=list('abc'))

# you can get a view using :2 slicing
my_slice = df.iloc[:, :2]
my_slice.iloc[0, 0] = 100

df
     a  b  c
0  100  2  1
1    3  4  1

my_slice
     a  b
0  100  2
1    3  4
```

This returns a view and hence doesn't copy, but I had index by slicing.

Now I try alternatives.

```py
my_slice = df.iloc[:, [0, 1]]
my_slice.iloc[0, 0] = 99

my_slice
    a  b
0  99  2
1   3  4

df
     a  b  c
0  100  2  1
1    3  4  1
```

Or

```py
my_slice = df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']]
my_slice.iloc[0, 0] = 55

my_slice
    a  b
0  55  2
1   3  4

df
     a  b  c
0  100  2  1
1    3  4  1
```

Thus, the last two attempts returned a copy. Again, this is just a simple example. In reality, I have many more columns and the location of the subset of columns I want to save may not be amenable to slicing. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe) is related, as it discusses selecting columns from dataframes, but it doesn't focus on being able to select views.

Comment: If it's just to save the data, then pretty much everything has an option to subset output by column labels... eg `df.to_csv('somefile.csv', columns=['a', 'f', 'z'])`

Comment: Good point. In my case I was using `to_hdf`, which doesn't appear to throw an error when I include a `columns` argument, but it does not save a subset of the columns.

Comment: Looks like it might be called `data_columns` according to [`DataFrame.to_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) ?

Comment: I think `data_columns` allows you to select some columns that you'd like to be able to use to query, but does not select a subset to be saved.

Comment: Okies... well, it's nearly 4am here and I'm knackered... but since a pandas DataFrame is a souped up 2D numpy array which you can get direct access to by (`df.values`) then the gory details are at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html for what makes a view and what doesn't and all that...