# Specific variables in sns.heatmap in python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to do a sns heatmap only from specific columns from my dataframe?
I have my dataframe named dt. It consists of columns A, B, C, D. 
Can I do a heatmap only from A, B,  and C?

I thought to do a list from my variables, like:
List = [A, B, C]
And then instead of doing dt.corr to do it on the list, but it doesn't seem to work. any suggestions?

```
sns.heatmap(dt.corr(), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths=.5, fmt= '.1f')
fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10,8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: if you replace `dt.corr()` by `dt[['A','B','C']].corr()` does it do what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Yes!!! thank you (: Is there a problem to put a list into corr? that's why I couldn't do it?