# Filter columns of the dataframe with specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter data of the columns according to string values, for example, I only need the columns that contain:
['CEMENTO MELON', 'G_CTRL_TE_DIEGO_DE_ALMAGRO','G_CTRL_EO_CANELA_2']

[image]

```
todos = []
for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    #Here must go the code
    todos.append(df)
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: try this, ```df[['CEMENTO MELON', 'G_CTRL_TE_DIEGO_DE_ALMAGRO','G_CTRL_EO_CANELA_2']]```

Comment: Here is another dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287278/4985099