# Print specific columns. Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This program outputs a table with two columns. Can I specify which columns you want to display?

```
def main():
    bulletins = os.listdir(INPUT_DATA_DIR)

    df = pd.DataFrame(bulletins)
    df.columns = ['filename']
    df['html'] = df.filename.apply(read_file)
    print(df.head())


def get_document_id(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    div = soup.find('div')
    print(div)

def read_file(filename):
    with open(INPUT_DATA_DIR / filename,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data
```

Now I have two columns, in the future there will be more. Can I output only certain columns? For example, can I output the first two columns?

At the moment I have this table:

```
filename                                               html
0    support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c008...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
1    support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c043...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
2    support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c008...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
3    support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c007...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
4    support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c018...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
..                                                 ...                                                ...
442  support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c009...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
443  support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c021...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
444  support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c009...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
445  support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c008...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...
446  support.hpe.com-hpesc-public-api-document-c008...  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...

[447 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Does your question is about displaying only the filename and html columns from the dataframe?

Comment: At the moment, Yes. But in General, I am interested in how you can print for example 3 columns out of 5

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe