# Pandas, Return a list of row contents for only specified columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    a   b   c
0   2   3   4
1   3   4   5
2   4   5   6

d = {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I have a dataframe similar to the one above. How can I get a list of the row contents for only certain columns?

For example, I want to get a list of row contents for columns `a` and `c` only, such that it looks like this:

```
contents = [[2,4], [3,5], [4,6]]
```

Comment: `df[["a", "b"]]`? But your output is for `df[["a", "c"]]`

Comment: `df[["a", "c"]].to_numpy().tolist()`

Comment: Using just pandas this would work: `[list(x[["a", "b"]]) for i, x in df.iterrows()]`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say a and c, that is fixed now.
@Ch3steR For your solution, how would I get those values into the list format that I show? What you did would just provide a filtered dataframe, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Ghoti Why is the whole expression in square brackets? Would that allow me to assign it as a list? like `contents = [list(x[["a", "b"]]) for i, x in df.iterrows()]`

Comment: @Paul Nope. `df[["a", "c"]]` to get filtered dataframe. `.to_numpy` to get underlying data. `.tolist` to convert everything to a list(same as your desired output).

Comment: @Ch3steR's solution is cleaner. Mine uses clunky list comprehension to force build the inner lists.

Comment: Do: `[list(t) for t in zip(df["a"], df["c"])]`

Comment: @Ch3steR You're solution worked well for what I was doing!! Could you add an answer so I can accept it?