# access to variable column

Tags: python, variables, dataset

I have a dataset in a folder and I would like to acceed to one of the contained variable just like `R` allows to do that via the following equivalent syntax:

```
dataset[dataset$name_of_interested_variable,]

or 

dataset1 = dataset%>%
    select(name_of_interested_variable)
```

Can anyone elucidate how to do the same with Python

Comment: Keep in mind that you can reach people who don't know R in detail only if you explain what dataset and variable exactly mean here.

Comment: So, you're interested in [selecting a column/columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: Thanks for helping