# How to filter pandas dataframe to select list of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 100 columns and I want to select list of variables

```
ID           A                  B                   C
    0  day1  day10  Δday   day1 day10  Δday    day1 day10  Δday
1   1  1.0   2.0    1.0    1.5  2.5    1.0     3.0  2.0    -1.0
2   2  3.0   5.0    2.0    1.0  2.5    1.5     3.0  5.0     2.0
3   3  2.5   3.5    1.0    1.5  2.9    1.4     3.5  4.0     0.5
............................................................
............................................................
```

```
df.columns

Index(['A', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'B', 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', 'C','Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8'],
      dtype='object')
```

How do I filter which should yield the output as:

```
A      B      C
Δday   Δday   Δday
1.0    1.0    -1.0
2.0    1.5     2.0
1.0    1.4     0.5
```

I looked at Pandas' documentation and tried filter regex, iloc but did not succeed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe). Also the question you asked vs the description you put in are two different things.

Comment: [`df.xs('Δday', level=1, axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)?

Comment: You dataframe image is is a little ambigous.  I am not sure why there is a space under ID, is that 0 in the index or under A?  Or is that 0 the second level index name?  Could you make a code that generates your input dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `slice(None)` to select any column at first level:

```
>>> df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'Δday')]

     A    B    C
  Δday Δday Δday
0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
1  2.0  1.5  2.0
2  1.0  1.4  0.5
```

To know more: [Using slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

**Update**

> Tried to applied and getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Your problem is because you don't use `read_excel` correctly. Your second row is not a column header but a simple row. Try to specify the header:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', ..., header=[0, 1])
```

Comment: Does it help to solve your problem?

Comment: Tried to applied and getting 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Are you sure you use `.loc` and not just `df[:, (slice(None), 'Δday')]`?

Comment: yes, with df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'Δday')]

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.columns` please?

Comment: thanks for the help.
I have updated. I am working with ms excel worksheet dataset

Comment: Thanks @Corralien
Now working correctly.