# Get DataFrame columns by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
values = ta.service(data["T"], data["H"])

print(values)
```

The variable `values` is a `DataFrame` and is printed as:

```
|            |     OT     |     OH     |
|------------|------------|------------|
| Timestamp  |            |            |
| 26-06-2020 | 19.54      |  NaN       |
| 03-07-2020 | 16.024     |  17.20     |
| 10-07-2020 | 19.26      |  25.89     |
----------------------------------------
```

I tried to get only the OT and OH columns in different ways, for example:

```
print(values.iloc[:, 1:2])
```

But, for this, I got:

```
|            |     OH     |
|------------|------------|
| Timestamp  |            |
| 26-06-2020 |  NaN       |
| 03-07-2020 |  17.20     |
| 10-07-2020 |  25.89     |
---------------------------
```

Shouldn't I get the columns 1 and 2, e.g., OT and OH? I also tried:

```
print(values.columns[1:2])
```

But I got:

```
Index(['OH'], dtype='object')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `.iloc` works like slicing, so last index is not included. you want `df.iloc[:, :2]` for the two columns. oh, and the `Timestamp` thingie is your index, not a usual column.

Comment: `values.columns`  gives you a list of your column names. If you want to obtain the specific column with values, you can do `values[values.columns[1:3]]`.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe, for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Quang Hoang, iloc works like slicing.
So you could do:

```
values.iloc[:,0:2]
```

or with labels

```
values.loc[:,["OH", "OT"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
values[["OT","OH"]]
```