# How to pivot multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Input Table

| index | income | Education | age1to_20 | pcd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | income_1 | Education_0 | 1 | A5009 |
| 2 | income_2 | Education_2 | 1 | A3450 |
| 3 | income_1 | Education_0 | 1 | A5009 |
| 4 | income_3 | Education_1 | 0 | A3450 |

How do I convert this table into

| index | income_1 | income_2 | INCOME_3 | Education_0 | Education_1 | Education_2 | age1to_20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A5009 | 0 | 0 | A5009 | 0 | 0 | A5009 |
| 2 | 0 | A3450 | 0 | 0 | 0 | A3450 | A3450 |
| 3 | A5009 | 0 | 0 | A5009 | 0 | 0 | A5009 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | A3450 | 0 | A3450 | 0 | 0 |

**UPDATED THE OUTPUT TABLE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
cols_to_pivot = ['income', 'Education']

cols = df.columns.difference(cols_to_pivot)
(df.melt(cols).drop(columns='variable')
   .pivot(index=['index', 'age1to_20'], columns='value', values='pcd')
   .fillna(0).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
value  index  age1to_20 Education_0 Education_1 Education_2 income_1 income_2 income_3
0          1          1       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
1          2          1           0           0       A3450        0    A3450        0
2          3          1       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
3          4          0           0       A3450           0        0        0    A3450
```

###### reworking column age1to_20

```
cols_to_pivot = ['income', 'Education']

cols = df.columns.difference(cols_to_pivot)
(df.assign(age1to_20=df['pcd'].where(df['age1to_20'].eq(1), 0))
   .melt(cols).drop(columns='variable')
   .pivot(index=['index', 'age1to_20'], columns='value', values='pcd')
   .fillna(0).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
value  index age1to_20 Education_0 Education_1 Education_2 income_1 income_2 income_3
0          1     A5009       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
1          2     A3450           0           0       A3450        0    A3450        0
2          3     A5009       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
3          4         0           0       A3450           0        0        0    A3450
```

Comment: what should I update to get pcd value filled for age1to_20 column?

Comment: what do you mean? You would like to have A5009/A3450/A5009/A3450 in place of 1/1/1/0?

Comment: yes. updated table. A5009/A3450/A5009/0

Comment: only issue is I am getting A5009 and A3450 as new columns

Comment: @nuke it doesn't do it with the provided example, if you want me to debug, please provide a DataFrame constructor that reproduces the issue

Comment: yes. it's correct. what if there are multiple columns like 'age1to_20'. Is there a better way to write rather than writing df.assign for every single column?

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([
    df.pivot(index=['index', 'age1to_20'], columns=['income'], values='pcd'),
    df.pivot(index=['index', 'age1to_20'], columns=['Education'], values='pcd')], axis=1)
 .fillna(0).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   index  age1to_20 income_1 income_2 income_3 Education_0 Education_1 Education_2
0      1          1    A5009        0        0       A5009           0           0
1      2          1        0    A3450        0           0           0       A3450
2      3          1    A5009        0        0       A5009           0           0
3      4          0        0        0    A3450           0       A3450           0
```

---

**EDIT**

In case there are a lot of columns to pivot, the following code does that, by iterating over the list of columns to pivot with `map`:

```
cols = ['income', 'Education']

(pd.concat(
    map(lambda x: df.pivot(
        index=['index', 'age1to_20'], columns=x, values='pcd'), cols), axis=1)
 .fillna(0).reset_index())
```

Comment: What if I have 20 columns that I need to pivot? Do I have to concat 20 pivot tables? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, @nuke, but that can be fully automated: Please, see my edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pivot once, run a for loop across the dataframe to get the individual dataframes, and concatenate across the columns, to get the final output:

```py
out = df.pivot(index=['index', 'age1to_20'], 
               columns=['income', 'Education'], 
               values = 'pcd')

out = [out.droplevel(axis=1,level=n) 
       for n in range(out.columns.nlevels)]

pd.concat(out, axis = 1).fillna(0, downcast='infer').reset_index()

   index  age1to_20 Education_0 Education_2 Education_1 income_1 income_2 income_3
0      1          1       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
1      2          1           0       A3450           0        0    A3450        0
2      3          1       A5009           0           0    A5009        0        0
3      4          0           0           0       A3450        0        0    A3450
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) allows us to get almost the desired output, but instead of getting the values as the `pcd` column, one has `0` or `1` for a given `pcd`

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['income', 'Education'])

[Out]:

   index  age1to_20  ... Education_Education_1  Education_Education_2
0      1          1  ...                     0                      0
1      2          1  ...                     0                      1
2      3          1  ...                     0                      0
3      4          0  ...                     1                      0
```

[image]

Then, in order to change the `1`s with the respective `pcd` value (and drop the column `pcd` at the end), one can use [`pandas.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) as follows

```
cols = df2.columns.drop(['index', 'pcd']) # To select the columns one wants to apply the change
df2[cols] = df2[cols].mask(df2[cols] == 1, df2['pcd'], axis=0)
df2 = df2.drop(['pcd'], axis=1) 

[Out]:

   index age1to_20  ... Education_Education_1 Education_Education_2
0      1     A5009  ...                     0                     0
1      2     A3450  ...                     0                 A3450
2      3     A5009  ...                     0                     0
3      4         0  ...                 A3450                     0
```

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- An alternative to change the `1`s to the respective `pcd` and drop the column `pcd` would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) as follows

  ```
  import numpy as np

  df2 = df2.assign(income_1 = np.where(df2['income_income_1'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                income_2 = np.where(df2['income_income_2'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                income_3 = np.where(df2['income_income_3'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                Education_0 = np.where(df2['Education_Education_0'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                Education_1 = np.where(df2['Education_Education_1'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                Education_2 = np.where(df2['Education_Education_2'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0),
                Age1to20 = np.where(df2['age1to_20'] == 1, df2['pcd'], 0)).drop(['age1to_20', 'income_income_1', 'income_income_2', 'income_income_3', 'Education_Education_0', 'Education_Education_1', 'Education_Education_2', 'pcd'], axis=1)

  [Out]:

     index income_1 income_2  ... Education_1 Education_2 Age1to20
  0      1    A5009        0  ...           0           0    A5009
  1      2        0    A3450  ...           0       A3450    A3450
  2      3    A5009        0  ...           0           0    A5009
  3      4        0        0  ...       A3450           0        0
  ```

  [image]
- There are additional ways to select the columns one wants to consider in a given dataframe. For that this might be useful: [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285613/7109869)