# Select the columns between two columns which we have only the name of them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to choose the columns between two different column which I only have their name. For example, in the following df, I want to select the columns between column `'a1'` and `'a4'`. I know that I can `df[['a1','a2', 'a3', 'a4']]`. However, my df is a very large df and I can not write it in this way.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2]
df['a1'] = [1, 2]
df['a2'] = [10, 12]
df['a3'] = [1, -2]
df['a4'] = [1, 12]
df['a5'] = [12, 20]
df['a6'] = [11, 3]
```

At the end I want this:

```
   a1   a2  a3  a4
0   1   10  1   1
1   2   12  -2  12
```

Do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `loc`. You can read more under [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

```
df.loc[:, 'a1':'a4']

   a1  a2  a3  a4
0   1  10   1   1
1   2  12  -2  12
```